# Raycasting walls arent drawed equally wide

Tags: javascript, canvas, raycasting

I am working on a raycaster and followed this tutorial: https://dev.opera.com/articles/3d-games-with-canvas-and-raycasting-part-1/

My questions is about a Bug which draws / calculates Walls in diffrent Width depending on where on the canvas its drawn (so how big the ray angle is to the players point of direction (center view)):
The Walls in drawn in the middle (1.) are small, but those on the left or right (2.) side of the screen are drawn wider. Its easiest to understand when you look at the image. I think I just got the Math wrong, maybe rounded up somewhere I shouldnt but I havent found it yet or could think of any reason this error accures. Its made in a HTML Canvas using JavaScript.

[image]

In my first function I am sending out a ray for each x pixel of my canvas:

```
let resolution = Math.ceil(canvas.width / this.resolution); //canvas width = 1600, resolution = 1
let id = 0;

    for (let x = 0; x < resolution; x++) {
        let viewDist = (canvas.width / this.resolution) / Math.tan((this.fov / 2)); //fov 90 in rad
        let rayx = (-resolution / 2 + x) * this.resolution;
        let rayDist = Math.sqrt(rayx * rayx + viewDist * viewDist);
        let rayAngle = Math.asin(rayx / rayDist);

        let wall = this.castWall(this.pod * Math.PI / 180 + rayAngle);
        this.drawWall(x, wall);
    }
```

But I dont think theres anything wrong here.  In the second function I am castinbg each ray and giving back the distance to the hit wall. My blocks / walls are 50 wide. My map is stored in and 2D number Array -> this.map.grid, this.map.width holds how many block there are in x direction, this.map.height holds the count in y direction.

```
castWall(angle) {
    const PI2 = Math.PI * 2;

    angle %= PI2;
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += PI2;
    }

    let right = angle > PI2 * 0.75 || angle < PI2 * 0.25;
    let up = angle < 0 || angle > Math.PI;

    let sin = Math.sin(angle);
    let cos = Math.cos(angle);

    let dist = 0;
    let textureX;
    let texture;

    let slope = sin / cos;
    let dXVer = right ? 1 : -1;
    let dYVer = dXVer * slope;

    let px = this.x / 50;
    let py = this.y / 50;

    let x = right ? Math.ceil(px) : Math.floor(px);
    let y = py + (x - px) * slope;

    while (x >= 0 && x < this.map.width && y >= 0 && y < this.map.height) {
        let wallX = Math.floor(x + (right ? 0 : -1));
        let wallY = Math.floor(y);

        if (this.map.grid[wallY][wallX] > 0) {
            dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - px, 2) + Math.pow(y - py, 2));
            texture = this.map.grid[wallY][wallX];
            textureX = (y * 50) % 50;

            if (right) {
                textureX = 50 - textureX;
            }
            break;
        }
        x += dXVer;
        y += dYVer;
    }

    slope = cos / sin;

    let dYHor = up ? -1 : 1;
    let dXHor = dYHor * slope;

    y = up ? Math.floor(py) : Math.ceil(py);
    x = px + (y - py) * slope;

    while (x >= 0 && x < this.map.width && y >= 0 && y < this.map.height) {
        let wallY = Math.floor(y + (up ? -1 : 0));
        let wallX = Math.floor(x);

        if (this.map.grid[wallY][wallX] > 0) {
            let distHor = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - px, 2) + Math.pow(y - py, 2));

            if (dist === 0 || distHor < dist) {
                dist = distHor;
                texture = this.map.grid[wallY][wallX];
                textureX = (x * 50) % 50;

                if (up) {
                    textureX = 50 - textureX;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        x += dXHor;
        y += dYHor;
    }

    return {
        distance: dist,
        texture: texture,
        textureX: textureX
    };`
```

Ive also tried raycasting with other algorithms (Bresenham & DDA) but I never got them really to work. This is the only one which works for me. If you have any questions about the code feel free to ask.

Comment: What are you observe called edge distortions and it is absolutely normal for standard FPS camera. You can reduce it using special technics but there is no need for that in general. See http://www.decarpentier.nl/lens-distortion

Comment: Okay thanks, I also did this: dist *= Math.cos(this.pod * Math.PI / 180 - angle); to eliminate the fishbowl effect, now its not really noticeable.